# Fetch Information from Facebook Login

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I want to know how can I access a user's name and email address from a Facebook-login button, that I have inserted in my site. I want to save the name and the respective score of the user, so that I can update them. I have tried many methods like graph API, access tokens but nothing has worked for me...... Am developing a game using Parse.

- I want to save the score and username including email on cloud code(Parse)
- Secondly I want to print the scoreboard in descending order automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have a good look at [Developers Site of facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.0.)

This is the direct specific link of what you want.

It provides you with 2 methods to facebook login and fetch user details (only those that do not need review). 
Since you have a button of your own so you will be needing the FB.login() method to login and get the user details. The documentation clearly explains the flow step by step right from Loading, initializing, calling the API etc. Have a look and tell where and what point seems confusing to you.

I assume that you have already done the SDK loading and initialization part. lets move to the login action and getting the user data.

> This is your button

```
<input type="button" value="Login Facebook" onclick="loginFacebook()" />
```

Now

```
<script>
/* Assuming Initialization and SDK loading done. Code is available there on the website */

 function LoginFacebook() {
    FB.login(function(response) { //This response here has the access token, signed request etc data.
       if (response.status === 'connected') {
             getUserInfo();
       } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
               // Not Autorized to use this.
        } else {
              // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
              // they are logged into this app or not.
        }
        });


   function getUserInfo() {
      FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email, function(response) {
           console.log(response); //Facebook returns a JSON object with this requested info
           console.log(response.name + "  " + response.email ); //or whatever you receive            
     });
   }
</script>
```

> I would also suggest you to use Facebook developer tools such as Facebook graph explorer to check the response of your API requests etc . I am sure it will help you alot by seeing what exactly is the response you get at every api request.

Comment: I have already read this thing,(FB.api) and  really appriciate your move, but i can't understand how to access those names, emails etc. Will they show up on javascript console or somewhere else , i just really can't understqand , how to connect the 2 pieces together